# Styling javascript document.write

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I am using a google map in a HTML5 page. I want to display the coordinates above the map in a paragraph, but when the following code is execusted it displays the variables on a blank white page.

How can i get the coordinates to be displayed above the map on the same page?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Geolocation With a Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function TestGeo()
    {
         if (navigator.geolocation) 
            {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( TestMap, error, {maximumAge: 3000000, timeout: 1000000, enableHighAccuracy: true} );
        }
        else
        {
              alert("Sorry, but it looks like your browser does not support geolocation.");
        }
    }
//Create a new map variable 
var map;
     function TestMap(position)
     {
           // Define the coordinates as a Google Maps LatLng Object
           var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

           // Prepare the map options
           var mapOptions =
          {
                      zoom: 10,
                      center: coords,
                      mapTypeControl: false,
                      navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            // Create the map, and place it in the map_canvas div
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            // Place the initial marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: coords,
                      map: map,
                      title: "Your current location!"
            });

        }

function error() {
        alert("Cannot locate user");
        }   

</script>

</head>
<body onload="TestGeo();">

<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><button onclick="location.href='takePicture.html'"><img src="/img/pic_icon.png" alt="Take Picture" /><br />Take<br />Picture</button>

                <button onclick="location.href='gallery.html'"><img src="/img/gallery_icon.png" alt="Gallery" /><br />Show<br />Gallery</button>
                <button onclick="location.href='recordsound.html'"><img src="/img/rec_icon.png" alt="Audio Recorder" /><br />Record<br />Sound</button>
                <button onclick="location.href='more.html'"><img src="/img/more_icon.png" alt="More Options" /><br />More<br />Options</button>
              </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
</header>

<section>
    <article>
        <script>
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;
            document.write('<p>Latitude: ' + lat + '<br>Longitude: ' + lon + '</p>');
        </script>
        <br />
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border-right: 1px solid #666666; border-bottom: 1px solid #666666; border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"></div>
    </article>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Updated code:

```
    <section>
    <article>
        <p>Latitude: <span id="lat"></span><br />Longitude: <span id="lon"></span></p>
        <script>
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = lat;
            document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML = lon;
        </script>
        <br />
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border-right: 1px solid #666666; border-bottom: 1px solid #666666; border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA; border-left: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"></div>
    </article>
</section>
```

This does not seem to print out the coordinates.

Comment: Never ever use `document.write` if you intend to use your app after 1997.

Comment: `Document.Write` is not for modifying the current document, it is for creating the (or a) document. You need to insert new elements (or html)

Comment: Ahh, explains where i am going wrong. I am very very new to JavaScript. So how exactly would i acheive what i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<script>
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    document.write('<p>Latitude: ' + lat + '<br>Longitude: ' + lon + '</p>');
</script>
```

To:

```
<p>Latitude: <span id="lat"></span><br />Longitude: <span id="lon"></span></p>
<script>
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = lat;
    document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML = lon;
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and it still does not function. I have updated my original question to show how i have implemented your solution. It does not seem to print out the values for the coordinates

Comment: The updated code looks right, did you get any error messages maybe?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors, it just does not want to work for some reason. The way i had it before worked fine and displayed the coordinates and it should really be displaying them here too.

Comment: The script like you have it in your question should raise an error. You're using the variable `position` outside of its function scope, therefore `position` is `undefined` at the place you use it.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` will overwrite the current page content, a simple solution would be to use document.body.innerHTML instead like so:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Latitude: ' + lat + '<br>Longitude: ' + lon + '</p>';
```

Please note that the `innerHTML` property is not a w3c standard (it is cross browser so it will still work on most browsers). For a standardized solution use DOM methods like `document.createElement`.

Comment: `innerHTML` is actually part of (X)HTML5
(http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0
http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml1)

Comment: Sorry, you're right, innerHTML is an html5 standard. Not sure what you meant by (X)HTML5 though (the X part).
IMHO the DOM methods are still a safer way to do this.

Comment: Regarding the 'X'-part, I copied it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML#Specification
You're right that DOM methods are better supported (at least way better than HTML5).